# Adding InfoWindow to Native Maps Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

What am I doing wrong here? The markers appear on the map but the infowindow doesn't. What should I do for this to work?

Thank you very much!

```
        this.map.addMarkerCluster({
            markers: markerClusters,
            icons: [ ... ]

        }).then((marker) => {
          marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
          .subscribe(()=>{

            var html = [
              'This is &lt;b&gt;Html&lt;/b&gt; InfoWindow',
              '&lt;br&gt;',
              '&lt;button onclick="javascript:alert(\'clicked!\');"&gt;click here&lt;/button&gt;',
            ].join("");
            // this.map. .setContent(html);

            this.infoWin.setContent(html);
            this.infoWin.open(marker);



          })


        })
```

Comment: What is the error is the infiwin undefined

Comment: I'm calling it from the class as `infoWin = new HtmlInfoWindow;`

Comment: Even i faced the same issue and I found out that infoWin was undefined it threw an error saying cannot find setContent of undefined